# Uncertainity regarding the proof from Rosenlicht's "Introduction to Analysis"

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, proof-explanation

I would be very grateful if somebody could explain me the part in the red rectangle in the proof below. I don't quite get it why the author claims that if $\delta$ is sufficiently small then $p+1\le q-1$. I don't get it why it is the consequence of the inequality $\beta-\alpha \le x_q-x_{p-1}<(q-p+1)\delta$. Thank you for the explanation.

---

[image]

Comment: I take issue with the author's terminology .It is not a "Riemann sum". It is a classic integration sum as developed independently by Newton and  Liebnitz about 200 years earlier than him. Riemann invented a type of integration that extended integrability to a broader class of functions, using a different type of sum.

Comment: Could you post some reference link? It's interesting. I would be happy to check that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\delta \leq (\beta - \alpha)/2$, then 
$$\beta - \alpha < (q-p+1)\delta \leq (q-p+1)(\beta-\alpha)/2,$$
hence 
$$2 < q - p + 1.$$
The desired inequality follows from this.

Put simply, as the step $\delta$ of the partition becomes small, some $x_i$'s must begin to appear between $\alpha$ and $\beta$. When that happens, the first $x_i$ to the right of $\alpha$ is less than or equal to the last $x_i$ to the left of $\beta$. The calculation given determines how small this $\delta$ has to be.